# Atribuir o valor de um input para uma variável php

Tags: php, html

Galera, tenho esse código e preciso atribuir o valor do select a uma variável php.
Como faço isso?

```
<form name="form-avaliacao" method="post" action="confirmacao-avaliacao.php">
                    <label>Disciplina *</label><br>
                    <select name="disciplina" id="disciplina" required>
                    <option>Selecione uma disciplina</option> 
                    <option>Artes</option>  
                    <option>Biologia</option> 
                    <option>Educação Física</option> 
                    <option>Filosofia</option>  
                    <option>Física</option> 
                    <option>Geografia</option>
                    <option>História</option> 
                    <option>Inglês</option>
                    <option>Matemática</option>
                    <option>Português</option> 
                    <option>Química</option> 
                    <option>Sociologia</option>
                    </select> <br><br>
```

Comment: Tem que enviar pro servidor o valor do select e fazer a atribuição no PHP. O problema é que a pergunta está muito rasa de informações.

Comment: A ideia é essa: Assim que o usuario selecionar umas das opções do select, a opção selecionada deverá ser gravada em uma variável. Depois faço um if com essa variável, para armazenar o valor dela no banco.

Comment: Exemplo: logo abaixo desse select teria isso:
<?php 
$select = o valor do select de cima
if($select == "Matemática")
{
    $categoria = $select;
    INSERT INTO tb_avaliacoes (categoria) VALUES = '$categoria';
}

Comment: Importante [edit] e postar o que tentou, e uma explicação do que não deu certo. Tutoriais, dicas e palpites [não fazem parte do perfil do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o formulário faz um post, você pode pegar o valor em `confirmacao-avaliacao.php` com `$_POST["NOME_DO_CAMPO"]`. O nome é identificado pelo `name` no HTML. No seu caso, seria então `$_POST["disciplina"]`.

Para mais detalhes, pode consultar https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Nossa, não tinha pensado nisso, talvez dê certo mesmo. Valeuu!

Comment: Só complementado o que o @tvdias disse acima. Você não postou todo o código html do seu formulário, é necessário que tenha um botão do tipo submit dentro desse formulário.